# Express.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, vue.js

I'm running a Universal Javascript application on Heroku.

My Vue.js app is being loaded by Express.js and requests are proxied to `https://localhost:3000/api`.

I am trying to make a simple POST request to an endpoint, however the console on Chrome prints out:

`OPTIONS https://localhost:3000/api net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

Here is my express server:

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import path from 'path'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import routes from './routes'

mongoose.connect('mongodb://coolAddress');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log("mongoose connected")
})

const app = express()

const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../coolClient/dist')));

app.use('/api', routes)

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../coolClient/dist', 'index.html'));
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on ${process.env.PORT || port}`)
})
```

I suspect this may have to do with SSL configuration. Googling the issue brings that possibility up, but doesn't provide much of an approach to debug it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show some code if you want help, in particular your express app setup.

Comment: @Paul ok edited. Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: I'm still not fully clear on your architecture.  Your app is on heroku, or it's on localhost?

Comment: @Paul Both my client app and API server are hosted on Heroku. The API server serves the client app itself

Comment: And the error is on the client or on the server?

Comment: @Paul it's on the client. Chrome console

Comment: Why is your client code trying to hit localhost if the server code is on heroku?

Comment: @Paul I guess because they are being served from the same server. Is that no good? If not, I just tried replacing localhost with the actual URL and the error changed to `OPTIONS https://app.herokuapp.com/api net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so from the comments, a few things to look at.

1) "localhost" means your computer.  If your client code is trying to hit that, it's going to need a server running on your machine and serving your server-side code.  You absolutely need to have a web-accessible domain name (like the one heroku provided you: app-name.herokuapp.com) to be able to hit your serverside code when it's hosted on heroku (or any other web host).

2) If you want to use HTTPS, then you have to buy and install an SSL certificate.  It won't be for the herokuapp domain, so you'll also need to buy a domain name and set that up for yourself.  All of that is explained on the heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I just completely misunderstood the relativity of localhost. Completely mindblown atm. Thanks for the info.

Comment: :) Can I harvest some of your wisdom for another issue I have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843836/express-js-route-execution-order-with-catch-all @Paul

Comment: That's funny, I asked the question there before seeing you ask me to

Answer (score 0):

I figured out and ssl requests working like a charm on my Centos6.9

- install virtualmin on your server
- setup Lets encrypt
- Just refer

before your call to
    `var app         = express();`
or any other http(s) mechanism or `app.listen(port),`

```
  var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/home/yourdomain/ssl.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/domain/ssl.cert'),
  };
```

Note: you must take in to account about 'No Access control allow origin'